# Gurobipy trip scheduling empty stop problem

Tags: modeling, gurobi, scheduling

I am trying to create an optimizing model for a roadtrip:
10 cities in 14 weeks.

For each city I have:

- a distance matrix to every city
- The rain for every week of the year

My goal is to minimize the traveling distance and the rain for each stop.

I already have a gurobi model but it has difficulties for the weeks without a new city: 1: Paris, 2: nothing, 3: Rome —> Traveling distance = 0 because D(Paris,nothing) = 0

Edit for a better understanding:

- My rain map has the following structure:

| week | city1_rain_in_mm | city2_rain_in_mm | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 12 | ... |
| 2 | 42 | 17 | ... |
| 3 | 37 | 27 | ... |
| 2 | 30 | 35 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

````py
# variables
is_planned = model.addVars(cities, weeks, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='x')
print(is_planned)

following_city = model.addVars(cities, cities, vtype=GRB.BINARY, lb=0, name='y')
print(following_city)

planned_week = model.addVars(cities, cities, vtype=GRB.BINARY, lb=0, name='z')
print(planned_week)

# minimize distance and rain
obj = gp.quicksum((following_city[city1, city2]*(dist[city1, city2])+(is_planned[city1,week]*(rain[city1,week])))
                    for city1 in cities for city2 in cities for week in weeks)

model.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)

# visit every city a single time
for track in tracks:
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(is_planned[city, week] for week in weeks) == 1)

# one city per week
for week in weeks:
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(is_planned[city, week] for city in cities) <= 1)


# is city1 followed by city2?
for week in weeks:
    if week < 47:
    for city1 in cities:
        for city2 in cities:
        if city1 != city2:
            model.addConstr((is_planned[city1,week] == 1) >> (following_city[city1, city2] == (is_planned[city1, week] + is_planned[city2, week + 1] - 1)))
        else:
            model.addConstr((is_planned[city1,week] == 0) >> (following_city[city1, city2] == 0))
```
````

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. If the mentioned answer is still not what you want, would you elaborate more on the problem details, specifically, the second goal (The rain)? Is it pre-determined or may it be depending on the traveling sequence? Also, It would be great if, you can illustrate it with a simple example.

Comment: @nimVo, thanks for clarifying. (just as a feasible solution) suppose we start in week1 in the city1. We need to stop around 45min here (the rain constraint) and then go to the city2 with distance, e.g. around 5 days. Again, we stop in the city2 around 12min and the process is repeated until we left on day 7 to enter the next week. Would you say, is it what you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

```
model= Model('travel')
is_planned = model.addVars(cities,weeks,vtype='b',name='x')
following = model.addVars(cities,cities,weeks[1:],vtype='b',name='y')
#visit every city a single time"
C1 = model.addConstrs((is_planned.sum(city,'*') >= 1 for city in cities),'CityOnce')
#Per week only One city"\
C2 = model.addConstrs((is_planned.sum('*',week) == 1 for week in weeks),'OneCityperWeek')
#If remaining in same city for more than a week"
C3 = model.addConstrs((following[city1,city2,week+1]>=is_planned[city2,week+1]+is_planned[city1,week]-1 for city1 in cities for city2 in cities for week in weeks[:-1]),'Following')
#Objective"
Distance = quicksum(dist[city1,city2]*following[city1,city2,week] 
                for city1 in cities for city2 in cities for week in weeks[1:])
Rain = quicksum(is_planned[city,week]*rain[week,city] for 
            city in cities for week in weeks)
obj = Distance+Rain
model.setObjective(obj,GRB.MINIMIZE)
model.update()
model.optimize()
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I add your constraint my model gets infeasible.

Comment: Now it may solve it with an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a network-based formulation with a directed acyclic network.  There is a node $i$ for each city-week pair $(c_i,w_i)$, as well as a dummy source node $s$ and a dummy sink node $t$.  There is an arc from node $i$ to node $j$ if $c_i \not= c_j$ and $w_i < w_j$.  For every node other than $s$ and $t$, there are arcs from $s$ and to $t$.  The cost for arc $(i,j)$ is the sum of the travel cost from $c_i$ to $c_j$ and the rain cost at city $c_j$ in week $w_j$.  Arcs $(s,j)$ from the source have zero travel cost, and arcs $(i,t)$ to the sink have zero cost.  The problem is to find a shortest path from $s$ to $t$, with a side constraint that every city is visited.

For a similar formulation for the *traveling baseball fan problem*, see https://blogs.sas.com/content/operations/2015/04/03/the-traveling-baseball-fan-problem/